# Maximum length of Apache Solr querystring when using Cygwin

Tags: solr, cygwin, query-string, maxlength

When my querystring to Apache Solr via Cygwin, like so:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/tt/select/?indent=on&facet=true&fl=id,title,(rest of querystring)
```

exceeds 1119 characters, a completely empty page is returned. When my query string is shorter than 1119 characters I do get results.

Also nothing is shown in the Cygwin console, which makes me guess the request never arrives.

Where can I configure the accepted maximum length of the query string?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: It's on my local machine: IIS7.5 on Windows 7, but these requests are completely handled by Cygwin anyway right?

Comment: Where and why is Cygwin involved in this?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin as my server to run Apache Solr...it's been a long time since I set this up, but I believe it was not possible/too hard to have it run via IIS.

Comment: I still don't understand what in Cygwin is serving Solr. httpd with some Java module? Why not just use Tomcat or Jetty like everyone else?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: I know, in the future I'll probably migrate to one of those, but for now the more pressing issue is understanding what is happening with my current issue.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: how can I check for an answer on your first question? how do I know what is serving Solr exactly? Thank you.

Comment: @Floran: as with all programs, Solr starts working when you invoke it from a service or command-line. What did you use to invoke it?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: these are the commands in my .bat file: 
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
bash -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Dropbox/Databases/apache-solr-3.5.0/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar"

Comment: @Floran then you're using Jetty. Look up how to configure the max request length in Jetty.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: I tried looking that up, but besides the fact I'm unable to find it, I also don't see a Jetty folder (or anything named Jetty for that matter) in my Cygwin folder. Do you have any idea where the jetty config files are so I can at least start looking for relevant property?